# Codeigniter how to fetch all the post data

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's suppose I have DOM like this :

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td"> 
        <select class="selCat" name="selCat[]">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="td"> 
        <p class="sub">text 1</p>
    </div>
 </div>   
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td"> 
        <select class="selCat" name="selCat[]">
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="td"> 
        <p class="sub">text 2</p>
    </div>
 </div>   
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td"> 
        <select class="selCat" name="selCat[]">
          <option>5</option>
          <option>6</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="td"> 
        <p class="sub">text 3</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Number of element with the name "selCat[]" is populated using codeigniter form_dropdown and is dynamic since it's based on user's input. User can add and remove the elements.

How can I get all the data from the same name "selCat[]". 
When I used

```
$data = $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);

        echo $data['selCat'];
```

it always returns the value of the last index.

Comment: `name="selCat[]"` name has to contain array key. e.g.: `name="selCat['a']"` Otherwise the last will be the only element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve my problem.
I don't need to give the index to the "selCat" nor array key.
Inside the controller, I can just use foreach

```
$selCat = $this->input->post('selCat');
        $data = $this->input->post(NULL,TRUE);

        foreach($selCat as $key => $row){

            echo $row;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give an index in your form. Here, the last value erases the previous one because you didn't specified it :

```
<select class="selCat" name="selCat[1]">...</select>
<select class="selCat" name="selCat[2]">...</select>
```

...
Then, server side, do something like this :

```
echo $data['selCat'][1]; // displays the first choice
echo $data['selCat'][2]; // displays the 2nd choice
```

And it should work.

Comment: I have edited my question. the number of elements with the name "selCat[]" is dynamic and is populated using codeignitier's form_dropdown therefore It's impossible for me to specify every index one by one manually.